# Preferred width of layout in 2012

Tags: html, css, layout, width, screen-resolution

I am working on new web app and still can't decide, what width of the layout I should choose. The app is based on Twitter Bootstrap's library and currently I use the **Default grid system** (with 12 columns), that has the width **1170px**.

On the monitor (I assume most of the people have the resolution higher than 1280px on width) looks the app good, the same on my MacBook PRO, but I am making a worries about the users with a bit older laptops, where the width-resolution is mostly **1024px** and the don't see whole layout (and will see the horizontal scrollbar).

So, I would like to ask you about your opinion. Do you optimize already the layout for a resolution > **1280px** or still you reflect the users with the res. **1024px** and use in that case the width **960px** for your layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **media queries** to change the layout for smaller resolutions. In my workplace, there are several monitors that are 1024 pixels wide. Also, people often use tablets in portrait mode (which, IIRC, only has 1024 pixels). Sure, the person *could* turn their tablet sideways to see the whole thing, but many people won't either out of sheer laziness or not realizing it would solve the problem.

If you only want to design for **one** resolution (read: you should not do this), then I wouldn't suggest anything larger than 1024 pixels wide. For some statistics, roughly 15-20% of our website's traffic uses monitors that are 1024 pixels or less wide.

It should also be noted that even for users with monitors 1280 pixels wide or wider, many users **do not maximize their browser windows**. This is especially common with Mac users, but can also be found with Windows/Linux users.

Comment: Yea, I update my layout size and use optimize it for the resolution on **1024px** and of course, I have to also check the **media queries**, I've never been working with yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3Counter's Global Stats](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) 15% of monitors are at 1024x768 and 56% have at least a width of 1280px.  I think 15% is still too high to go with 1170px as a layout.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I develop for 1024px and up for desktops. I use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries) to detect mobile devices and provide an alternative layout.

As SupremeDud states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10210617/383609), 15% of displays are still 1024x768, which is a reasonably large market share.

In terms of a pixel width, I base designs around 960px. You might want to look at [960.gs](http://960.gs/), although I'm not sure how it will work with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

How about liquid or responsive layout? That way you can cover all resolutions and window sizes.